# 5 Quotes 1 Figure

Tags: history, word-search

These are 5 quotes all made by the same historically famous person that have all been transcribed slightly differently.

***What are each of the quotes and who said them all?***

> ```
> SETAERGRUO
> TBGNILLAFR
> GUMITYREVE
> LTEWEFALEV
> OINRISINGE
> RYISNOTINN
> ```
>
> ```
> DETACILPMO
> NIEWTUBELC
> SRSIEFILPT
> IEALLYSIMI
> STONMAKING
> ```
>
> ```
> ITYODTP
> ETTOLOO
> YRDAUSN
> NLHOMGA
> UGWOETO
> SOAOWSO
> OTYSLSN
> ```
>
> ```
> TAHLETWHIELSL
> ETAORWEITNHTE
> HKEEDYESSTIHR
> AETTWOISLULCU
> CNELEODCTKHTE
> HUERDGOEOTROT
> ROEPAECRHSYOO
> NUARLFEUXLCLE
> PLOLTEENNCTEI
> ```
>
> ```
> ETRTHEGOSSASY
> UEOTVNYAEEETT
> VNYEIRHNBEUIB
> ```

Comment: should be shakespeare

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Partial answer.

1

> Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.

How to solve:

> Start from upper right corner backwards and in a spiral.

2.

> Life is really simple, but we insist on making it complicated.

How to solve:

> Similar to one, only this time the spiral starts in the middle.

For the rest:

> The rest seemed at first more or less scrambled (although the 3rd had some recognizable pattern) so I searched for more quotes of Confucius which would match the letters. And the 5th was solved by IAmInPls.

3.

> It does not matter how slowly you go as long as you do not stop.

Another bad drawing to show the pattern:

> [image]

4.

> The will to win, the desire to succeed, the urge to reach your full potential... these are the keys that will unlock the door to personal excellence.

How to solve:

> **T**A**H**L**E**T**W**H**I**E**L**S**L**
>   E**T**A**O**R**W**E**I**T**N**H**T**E
>   **H**K**E**E**D**Y**E**S**S**T**I**H**R**
>  A**E**T**T**W**O**I**S**L**U**L**C**U
>  **C**N**E**L**E**O**D**C**T**K**H**T**E**
>  H**U**E**R**D**G**O**E**O**T**R**O**T
>  **R**O**E**P**A**E**C**R**H**S**Y**O**O**
>  N**U**A**R**L**F**E**U**X**L**C**L**E
>  **P**L**O**L**T**E**E**N**N**C**T**E**I**

5. Thanks to @IAmInPLS

> Everything has beauty, but not everyone sees it.
>
>  The pattern : (mad Paint skills, be careful.)
>
>  [image]

Author of the quotes:

> Confucius

Comment: Impresive, I wasn't expecting an answer that fast lol

Comment: Not complete yet. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva I found the last one. Good job, you were fast!

Comment: @IAmInPLS I hate these situations, I never know who to give credit to lol. Maria got most of the answer, but you were the first to write the complete one...

Comment: @dcfyj Ha, I understand your concern lol. Anyway, give the tick to MariaDeleva of course, she was the first to write the most of it.

Comment: @dcfyj, I had a similar situation with my last question - I wish I could credit more people - and not only with a single upvote.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Some reasoning, pls?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov, I edited my answer.

Comment: @MariaDeleva They actually all have a distinct pattern to them.

Comment: @dcfyj, I still can't see the pattern in 5. Perhaps, if IAmInPLS, found the patterns themselves, the tick should go to him.

Comment: Disappointingly, the first quote seems to be by [someone else.](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/05/27/rising/)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Va ernyvgl, gur svsgu obk vf whfg rirel bgure yrggre tbvat qbjajneqf. [ROT13](http://www.rot13.com/) (This is the encoding for the fifth answer, don't look at it if you want to figure it out yourself)

Comment: @dcfyj - Gung jbhyq unir orra zber nccnerag jvgu n sbhegu yvar V qb oryvrir. Vg unccrarq gb or qvntbany qhr gb gurer orvat bayl guerr. [ROT13](http://www.rot13.com/) (Encoded response only because I mention parts of the algorithm as well)

Comment: @Shimizoki But I had to make perfect boxes :P

Answer (score 7):

@MariaDeleva found most of them but I am adding them here anyway (she was *way* too fast, I did not even have time to build a proper answer).

> Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.
>
>  Life is really simple, but we insist on making it complicated.
>
>  It does not matter how slowly you go as long as you do not stop.
>
>   The will to win, the desire to succeed, the urge to reach your full potential... these are the keys that will unlock the door to personal excellence.

Last one is :

> Everything has beauty, but not everyone sees it.

And they are all quotes by :

> [Confucius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucius).

Answer (score 7):

Partial Encoding Answer:

This is just to solve the encoding that Maria did not see, all credit for the solutions go to them.

3:

> It is encoded in <strike>CCW spiral of diagonal stripes from upper left to lower right.</strike> diagonal stripes that loop back on themselves. It is more like an onion that is building on itself. The middle stripe, then CCW around the 1 line, then CW around the now 3 lines, then CCW around the now 5 lines.

4:

> It is encoded by using every other letter 1, 3, 5, 7 ... when you get to the end, it wraps around to the beginning 2, 4, 6, 8...

5:

> It is encoded using diagonal alternating lines. / Start in the upper left (E), then go down 2 and read up and right for the next 3 (VER), then go down 2... Think of it like a sideways barber pole.

Comment: 3 is partially correct and 5 is sort of on the right track.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I finally saw the pattern in 5.

Comment: Looking at IAmInPLS's edit I see how you mean, while that does work that's not how I saw it when I wrote lol.

Comment: @dcfyj - fixed 3 I think...

Comment: @dcfyj - 3 starts in the middle diagonal downwards, and then goes to the sides (first one side, then the other, in alternate directions).

Comment: @MariaDeleva you could always draw a picture and put it in your answer :P

Comment: @dcfyj - I tried (the picture), didn't work out good. :) But will try again.